# Looking for WFS-T which data I can edit in QGIS for testing purposes

Tags: qgis, wfs-t, server, testing

I'm in a situation where I have to make sure, that a WFS-T solution for qgis works on my office-desktop here in a secured network, before the responsible IT-department can creates an environment with webserver, database and qgis-server for that.

Has anyone an idea, where I can find a WFS-T which I can edit and save back to prevent reactions from IT like "make sure it works in this network with that proxy before wasting my time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search for "wfs t demo" suggests e. g.:

http://boyang.cs.uwm.edu:8080/geoserver/www/wfs-t.html which uses http://boyang.cs.uwm.edu:8080/geoserver/wfs

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for. "Stackexchange" said to me: "You can't [down]vote for your own post." and as new member I can't upvote yours and for that I'm sorry.

Comment: No worries, friend!